# when one of zones enter full disruption, we update eviction qps to which value for this zone

Tags: kubernetes

I think when zone ,for example zone-1, enters full disruption, we shouldn't evict node in this zone, that is to say, we should set limiter qps=0.

However when i check code, unexpected result:

```
nc.enterFullDisruptionFunc = nc.HealthyQPSFunc

func (nc *Controller) HealthyQPSFunc(nodeNum int) float32 {
return nc.evictionLimiterQPS
}

func (nc *Controller) setLimiterInZone(zone string, zoneSize int, state ZoneState) {
switch state {
case stateNormal:
    if nc.useTaintBasedEvictions {
        nc.zoneNoExecuteTainer[zone].SwapLimiter(nc.evictionLimiterQPS)
    } else {
        nc.zonePodEvictor[zone].SwapLimiter(nc.evictionLimiterQPS)
    }
case statePartialDisruption:
    if nc.useTaintBasedEvictions {
        nc.zoneNoExecuteTainer[zone].SwapLimiter(
            nc.enterPartialDisruptionFunc(zoneSize))
    } else {
        nc.zonePodEvictor[zone].SwapLimiter(
            nc.enterPartialDisruptionFunc(zoneSize))
    }
case stateFullDisruption:
    if nc.useTaintBasedEvictions {
        nc.zoneNoExecuteTainer[zone].SwapLimiter(
            nc.enterFullDisruptionFunc(zoneSize))
    } else {
        nc.zonePodEvictor[zone].SwapLimiter(
            nc.enterFullDisruptionFunc(zoneSize))
    }
}
```

}

I dont't know why we return nc.evictionLimiterQPS instead of 0.

Comment: Where did you get this code from? Can you provide any links to the code, or is it your own code?

Comment: @Crou  Thanks for reponse. The code is from kubernetes code repository.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/nodelifecycle/node_lifecycle_controller.go#L308

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/nodelifecycle/node_lifecycle_controller.go#L1184

Comment: Maybe it's right.When one zone enters full disruption but others not, possibly this zone is down, so we should evict this zone at normal rate.

Comment: Have you posted this on Kubernetes github?